# ¿Cómo puedo detectar si en mi cadena de texto hay caracteres que no sean en español?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Estoy intentando de encontrar la manera de verificar los datos que reciben los usuario, ellos revicen un texto como por ejemplo `4010XS-1清关发票E` que en español es `1 factura de despacho de aduana E`, pero lo que intento hacer es que el texto solo se quede con los caracteres en español quedaría como ejemplo `4010XS-1E` o parecido. Si no se puede, que al menos detecte que hay caracteres que no están en español y así yo mismo asignarles otro nombre. La idea que tengo por ahora es esta

```js
const textoChino = "4010XS-1清关发票E"
const textoSinChino = "4010XS-1E"
const textoEspaniol = "mifactura"
const regexr = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/g

//ambos me devuelven falso, como puedo dectar si uno es chino?
console.log(regexr.test(textoChino)) 
console.log(regexr.test(textoSinChino)) 
console.log(regexr.test(textoEspaniol))
```

Comment: La pregunta esta bien.. solo como nota, queres sacar caracteres que no pertenezcan al alfabeto latino (o romano, tiene varios nombres).. lo aclaro porque hay lenguajes que usan las mismas letras y no son español....

Comment: Por lo que veo la **g** del final está molestando. Además de que la segunda cadena tiene un carácter que no está en el regex, el guión (`-`)

Comment: Prueba con esto:  `const regexr = /^[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ-]+$/`, así tambien te cogerá acentos

Comment: si eso esta bine, por lo menos me salio que `textoSinChino` es true muchas gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy abierta. ¿Solo necesitas detectar si la cadena está en chino o en español o en cualquier otro lenguaje? Porque si lo que buscas es detectar el idioma de la cadena lo veo complicado a menos que te apoyes de algún third-party data que te ayude a identificar el lenguaje de la o las palabras que tengas. Por otro lado, si solo buscas que esté en chino o en español, creo que puedes probar tener un array con todas las letras en chino y otro array con las letras en español y así con un `indexOf` hacer una validación.

Comment: @FernandoTorres Eso no seria mas complicado?, aparte no siempre le llegan ese texto, pueden ser distintos, lo que trataba de hacer es solamente si la cadena tiene algún carácter que no sea en español. En ese caso yo mismo puedo ponerle otro nombre, un correlativo o algo así.

Comment: @JheffersonAlbornozVara Creo que la complejidad va en función de lo que quieras hacer. Si la cadena tiene algún caracter que no sea en español creo que pudieras apoyarte del ASCII Code y del Chinese Character Code for Information Interchange

Answer (score 1):

Se me ha ocurrido hacer esto:

```
const chineseText = "4010XS-1清关发票E"
const notChineseText = "4010XS-1E"
const spanishText = "mifacturaáéñÑ"
const regex = /[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*-*/g

function isSpanish(str) {
    return str.replace(regex, '').length === 0
}

console.log(isSpanish(chineseText)) // ---> false
console.log(isSpanish(notChineseText)) // ---> true
console.log(isSpanish(spanishText)) // ---> true
```

Es una función que te dice si es español al eliminar todos los caracteres que pertenecen a esa lengua y no queda ningún carácter en el string. Puede coincidir con otros idiomas, pero con el chino o ruso por ejemplo, no.

Te diría que le añadas todos los caracteres especiales a la regex que creas que puedan aparecer.

Si necesitas añadir algún carácter a la regex me lo dices y edito la respuesta.